# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException for algorithm "PBE WITH MD5 AND 256 BIT AES-CBC-OPENSSL"

Tags: java, android, cryptography

I am using following code snippet for getting factory instance of specified algorithm. But it is throwing a `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException`. I am using this in my java project with jre1.6.

Is it require any external library(jar)? The same code when I tried in my Android app, it's working fine.

```
try {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

```
Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
if (null == providers) {
    System.out.println("Providers are not available.");
    return;
}

for (Provider provider : providers) {
    System.out.println("Provider: " + provider.getName());
    Set<Provider.Service> services = provider.getServices();
    for (Provider.Service service : services) {
        System.out.println("\tAlgorithm: " + service.getAlgorithm());
    }
}

try {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(providers[0].getServices().iterator().next().getAlgorithm());
    if (null == factory) {
        System.out.println("Getting instance of specified algorithm failed.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Success.");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above is edited code and is throwing following exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA1PRNG SecretKeyFactory not available
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
```

Comment: Which JCE provider are you using?

Comment: stack trace of exceptions is as follows:    java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL SecretKeyFactory not available
     at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(DashoA13*..)
     at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)

Comment: I haven't specified any JCE provider. I am using JCE library 6.0

Comment: Capitalization? Here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#spectemp they use 'And' and 'With' I also don't see that they have `CBC-OPENSSL` padding scheme

Comment: With so few tags (just the [tag:java] tag at the time of writing), you can be certain it won't be picked up by the crypto community here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"PBEWITHMD5AND256BITAES-CBC-OPENSSL"` is part of the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org) provider, you may have to download that library to use it on Java SE. Don't forget to download the [unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) too.

As for the second exception, if you just ask the algorithm of the first service of the first provider, you get get an algorithm that is only valid for a specific **type**. In this case it is usable only for `SecureRandom`, not for `SecretKeyFactory` as you would have found if you had replaced `.getAlgorithm()` with `.getType()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(String algorithm)`:

> `algorithm` - the standard name of the requested secret-key algorithm. See Appendix A in the Java Cryptography Architecture Reference Guide.

and so you should expect and error when calling `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")` which isn't valid according to that document.

Comment: For "DES" it's working fine, but what about other algorithms? Because I am getting list of providers and algorithms supported by them. What to do in order to use any algorithm supported by the providers which getProviders() method returns?

Comment: Here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html, the documentation for getInstance method directs you to this document for valid algorithm names http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#AppA .That document contains a bunch of examples which you may find useful. It also contains a reference to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html. Search for 'SecretKeyFactory Algorithms'

Comment: @DavidSoroko Posted an answer as well, if you are interested. Added cryptography tag, missed this question completely (of course).

Answer (score -1):

Perform the steps here. I did and the result was successful.

Step 1. Download the Bouncy Castle provider for your JDK or JRE (bcprov-jdk16-146.jar for JDK 1.6);

Step 2. Copy the provider .jar file to the Java Runtime (JRE) extensions subfolder; for a Windows machine the JRE 1.6 (if it exists) is installed usually in:
example:C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\jre\lib\ext

Step 3. add the Bouncy Castle provider to the java.security file to enable it; the file is located in the \lib\security\ subfolder from the JRE location (Attention ! Both locations – the standalone JRE and the one from the JDK); edit the file and add the statement

security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
Note: N must be the next number in sequence.

Visit --> http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/22/how-to-use-bouncy-castle-cryptographic-api-in-netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-jse-projects/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, answers must be more than just a link. You should edit your answer, to include a summary of the solution described at that link. If not, you can delete your answer and post this as a comment under the question. Link-only answers are subject to deletion by moderators on SO.